# Do Math on SQL query results

Tags: mysql, sql

1)  List the names and per capita GNP in dollars for countries with a population of at least 200 million. (Per capital GNP is the GNP per person, so the GNP divided by the population. Note that the GNP is expressed in millions, so to get an actual dollar amount you’ll also need to multiply by 1,000,000)

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Name, GNP FROM country WHERE Population >= 200000
```

This is what I have so far for the math portion

```
SUM((GNP / Population) * 1000000)
```

But I'm not sure where to put that expression, or how to do it on the GNP results... Help!

Comment: In the select clause itself...but why use SUM?

Comment: Your current `WHERE` clause is checking for countries with 200K, not 200 million, population.

Comment: Please show your table definition(s) and what a row in each states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you even need to use `SUM()` here, because each record in your `country` table already represents an aggregate that country's entire population.  Just use this:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    GNP,
    (GNP / Population) * 1000000 AS PCGNP
FROM country
WHERE Population >= 200000000
```